# SQL Server "NOT IN" taking a lot of time

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the SQL query shown below in SQL Server to load the data every week. To avoid duplicates, I have been using `NOT IN` to check the table which I'm inserting.

This query takes long time and it hangs occasionally. Only a few thousands rows are being inserted every week

```
INSERT INTO [ST_FACT]
    SELECT 
        H.WK_DATE,
        H.[M_Code]
    FROM 
        T_FACT H
    WHERE 
        H.WK_DATE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(WK_DATE) 
                          FROM ST_FACT 
                          WHERE RETAILER LIKE '%MSI%')
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the `not in` that's slow? Could it be that the `WHERE RETAILER LIKE '%MSI%'` is the slow part? See how long that subquery takes to run.

Comment: Thanks,it runs very quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO [ST_FACT]
    SELECT H.WK_DATE, H.[M_Code]
    FROM T_FACT H
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ST_FACT f
                      WHERE H.WK_DATE = f.WK_DATE AND RETAILER LIKE '%MSI%'
                     );
```

For this to work, create an index on `ST_FACT(WK_DATE, RETAILER)`.